# DataTables fnDeleteRow from popup window

Tags: jquery, datatables

When a user interacts with a form that is in a popup JavaScript window, I want to delete a row in a DataTable in the main window. I'm not sure how to address the table and specific row. The table id is `"contentMR"` and the id of the TR element to delete is `"1234"`. I have tried

```
opener.contentMR.fnDeleteRow( $("#1234") );
opener.contentMR.fnDeleteRow( $("#1234")[0] );
opener.document.contentMR.fnDeleteRow( $("#1234") );
opener.document.contentMR.fnDeleteRow( $("#1234")[0] );
```

I've used opener a lot in the past but not in conjunction with jQuery syntax and I'm not sure I'm passing the row ID correctly either. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a couple issues. I was failing to do a ...

```
mrTable = $('#contentMR').dataTable();
```

So I needed to be doing mrTable.fnDeleteRow() instead of contentMR.fnDeleteRow().

Then, instead of trying to call it directly from my popup window I needed to define a function on the main window and then call that function. The function on the main page is

```
function removeRow(itemID)
{
mrTable.fnDeleteRow( $("#" + itemID)[0] );
}
```

and then the code that calls it from the popup window is simply...

```
opener.removeRow(entryID);
```